# Android Kotlin .visibility

Tags: android, imageview, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have this code that is supposed to make an image visible, but I don't know exactly how it's supposed to be written for Kotlin.

I'm trying to use `.visibility` in Kotlin, and I don't know what to give it for a value. It's based off of `setVisibility()`.

Code:

```
fun hacerVisibleLaFoto(v: View) {
    imageView.visibility = 1;
}
```

I put `1` in the value spot because an integer value is required there, and that's my placeholder value until I find what really goes there.

What should go after the `=` sign to make the value visible?

Comment: this is not really related to kotlin

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Android has static constants for [view visibilities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)). In order to change the visibility programmatically, you should use `View.VISIBLE`, `View.INVISIBLE` or `View.GONE`.

Setting the visibility using `myView.visibility = myVisibility` in Kotlin is the same as setting it using `myView.setVisibility(myVisibility)` in Java.

In your case:

```
fun hacerVisibleLaFoto(v: View) {
    imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `View.VISIBLE`. That is a constant defined in `View` class.

```
fun hacerVisibleLaFoto(v: View) {
    imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
View.VISIBLE
```

Should go after the = sign to make the value visible. It has integer constant value in View class. You can check it by pressing ctrl + click (Windows) or cmd + click (Mac).

So it should be like this.

```
imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of some of Kotlin's language features, I use these two extension methods on `View` that toggle the visibility with a boolean as a convenience.

```
fun View.showOrGone(show: Boolean) {
    visibility = if(show) {
        View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        View.GONE
    }
}

fun View.showOrInvisible(show: Boolean) {
    visibility = if(show) {
        View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        View.INVISIBLE
    }
}
```

Basic usage:

```
imageView.showOrGone(true) //will make it visible
imageView.showOrGone(false) //will make it gone
```

Although if you are looking for just a little syntactic Kotlin sugar to make your `View` visible, you could just write an extension function like so to make it visible.

```
fun View.visible() {
    visibility = View.Visible
}
```

Basic usage:

```
imageView.visible()
```

Comment: More clean solution: 

    fun View.showOrGone(show: Boolean) {
        visibility = if(show) View.VISIBLE  else View.GONE 
    }

Answer (score 2):

> Very easy and simple
>
> To visible a view :

```
ViewName.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

e.g.- `button.visibity = View.VISIBLE`

To invisible a view :

```
ViewName.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

e.g.- `button.visibity = View.INVISIBLE`

> Anything you can use like button, textview, image view etc
>
> Hope this would work.